# Carrierwave store_dir not modified when running rspec with spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave, spork

I've followed the [instructions on how to define a test-specific store directory for carrierwave uploads](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Cleanup-after-your-Rspec-tests), which suggests opening the `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base` class and redefining `store_dir` and `cache_dir` like so:

```
if defined?(CarrierWave)
  CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants.each do |klass|
    next if klass.anonymous?
    klass.class_eval do
      def cache_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/tmp"
      end 

      def store_dir
        "#{Rails.root}/spec/support/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end 
    end 
  end
end
```

This works like a charm, except when I run rspec with spork, then it fails to modify the class and uploads are stored in the default location. Does anyone have any clue why this might be happening?

Comment: What is the difference between store and cache_dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone else working on our project solved this problem by adding a line with just `AvatarUploader` ahead of the `CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants.each` line, like this:

```
if defined?(CarrierWave)
  AvatarUploader # load AvatarUploader class 
  CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants.each do |klass|
  #...
```

Not entirely sure why this works, but it does.

Comment: FYI this now results in `DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constant AvatarUploader` - check ["Autoloading and Reloading Constants" guide to learn more](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)

Answer (score 1):

Little addition to accepted answer, for anyone coming here:

if uploader classes are not loaded before the call to 
CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants, it will return empty array, so either specify each uploader like in accepted answer or you could do something like this to require all uploaders from let's say rails uploaders folder

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/uploaders/*.rb"].each {|file| require file}
CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.descendants.each do |klass|
#...
```